# How can i submit HDInsight jobs from nodejs/REST api

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

I'm looking for a way to submit Pig/Hive jobs from within my node.js application. For this I would like some sort of node.js sdk or REST Api to the service. Is there such a thing.

I did some research and the official npm azure package only handles hdinsight cluster creation, listing and deletion. What I would like is to be able to programmatically submit jobs to the cluster, not by using the power shell  (I'm on linux vms) as shown in the http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/hdinsight/submit-hadoop-jobs-programmatically/ tutorial

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HDInsight service has a REST API called WebHCat (formerly Templeton, so you might see that in the docs) which you can use from node easily enough.

The documentation is here http://hive.apache.org/docs/hcat_r0.5.0/rest.html

To just submit a job, the call you're looking for is:

https://mycluster.azurehdinsight.net/templeton/v1/hive

You just post it a query in the execute parameter (form encoded). There are a few other options to do with status location, and completion callbacks which will maybe useful in your application, all documented at http://hive.apache.org/docs/hcat_r0.5.0/hive.html

Note that the templeton instance in HDInsight runs on the standard ssl port (443) rather than the templeton default used in other distributions (50111)

Comment: The link you provided, http://mycluster.azurehdinsight.net/templeton/v1/hive, this is just a template, right? How can I expose my hdinsight cluster through http?

Comment: Yes, you need to replace mycluster with the name you gave it obviously. The cluster will already have HTTP open to provide this interface.

Comment: OK, I replaced `mycluster` with the name I've given my hdinsight cluster when I created it and it **doesn't** work ie. it eventually timeouts, but it doesn't through 404. Can you please point me to the documentation on how WebHCat endpoints are setup in azure. 10x for your help!

Comment: My apologies, should have been https, and you'll need basic auth with the cluster username and password you specified on creation. I've edited to correct.